# Combining Linq Queries with ANDs or Ors

Tags: linq, expression-trees

I have a problem as depicted below:

```
var customers = from c in ctx.Customers;
```

Dynamically from UI, I can pass a list of filters
Scenario 1. "AND"

```
groupOp = "AND"
filter 1: where c.ID == 1
filter 2: where c.Name == 'XYZ'
```

What I need is a way to combine
so end result is:

```
var filterList = from c in ctx.Customers
                 where c.ID == 1
                 && c.Name == 'XYZ'
```

Scenario 2. "OR"

Same problem

var customers = from c in ctx.Customers;

Dynamically from UI, I can pass a list of filters

```
groupOp = "OR"
filter 1: where c.Name == 'ABC'
filter 2: where c.Name == 'XYZ'
```

What I need is a way to combine
so end result is:

```
var filterList = from c in ctx.Customers
                 where c.Name == 'ABC'
                 || c.Name == 'XYZ'
```

How can I dynamically combine the IQueryable with AND or OR. At the moment I have no requirement to combine AND and ORs so its just either AND or OR.
Any Help greatly appreciated always...

Answer (score 2):

Use [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx), i.e.

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Customer>();
foreach (var filter in filters)
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(filter);
}
return ctx.Customers.Where(predicate);
```

If you don't want to manually build all the filter expressions manually in code, you might benefit from using the [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) library build expressions from strings.

Comment: The problem is my Types are Dynamic and not known till runtime.Sorry for not providing this info.

Comment: Did you look at the second link in my answer (I edited it) to the Dynamic Linq library? You shouldn't need to know the types at compile-time if you're using Dynamic Linq because it is all based on strings.